How to show that the linear interpolation from a point inside a closed set to a point outside it contains a boundary point of that set?
So I have a closed set $S$, and for $r_0 \in S$ and $r_1 \not\in S$ I want to show that $\exists t\in [0,1]$ such that
$r(t)=r_0+t(r_1-r_0)\in B$ where $B$ is the boundary of $S$.
What I tried is bisection in $t$, where starting from with the bounds $t_1=1$ and $t_2=0$ I just iteratively halve the difference between my $t$ limits ensuring that $r(t_1)\not \in S$ and $r(t_2)\in S$ using standard bisection.
With this, I can then get that $\forall c>\epsilon>0$ where $c$ is some finite upper limit, I have considering the bisection past some calculable number of iterations that $\exists \hat{t}\in [0,1]$ such that $r(\hat{t})\in S$ and $r(\hat{t})+\epsilon (r_1-r_0) \not \in S$.
Is this sufficient to say that $\exists t\in [0,1]$ such that $r(t) \in B$? It seems like it's almost showing that there exists a $t\in [0,1]$ such that $r(t)$ specifies a point in $S$ with any arbitrarily small ball about that point not being inside $S$ when considering $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small, but I'm not sure.

Just let $t = \sup{t \in [0, 1] : r(t) \in S}$. The assumption that $S$ is closed should not be necessary (though it is necessary if you further want $r(t) \in S$, not just $r(t) \in B$).

Oh wow, I feel stupid. Thanks!
